# Window.open() not working in liferay portlet

Tags: java, liferay

i want to open a pdf file from a liferay portlet. i tried using window.open() but its not working out for me. the pdf file is residing in c:\MyFolder

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="" onclick="javascipt:window.open('C:\\MyFolder\\a.pdf');" class="popup">Click to open.</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On clicking the link the page redirects to `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/`.  Would really appreciate someone's help.

Comment: You can't open a `PDF` file in Browser which is residing on client m/c. Please do some research before posting such question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open a `PDF` in a new `Window` the url should point to any of the following

1. `PDF` file residing on `Server`
2. Any URL where `Server` is capable of streaming a `PDF`
3. `ResourceURL` where your Portlet's `serveResource` streams a `PDF`